# ¿Como saber cual es el primer hijo directo de un elemento div con CSS y realizar acción si es ta o no?

Tags: html, css, tinymce

Resulta que estoy utilizando TinyMCE y necesito realizar mi propio placeholder. El placeholder que se pasa por  `tinymce.init` no funciona en etiqueta `<div>` que así necesito iniciar con ese bloque y que el contenido se cree dentro.

El escenario es el siguiente:
Tengo creado un componente de TinyMCE *texto en itálica*iniciado el contenido con `<div class="editable"></div>`, pero cuando lo pasa por el editor de texto enriquecido TinyMCE a ese div le agrega un `<br data-mce-bogus="1">` quedando de la siguiente manera: **(Aquí si esta correcto debe mostrar el placeholder)**

```css
div.editable:first-child:has([data-mce-bogus="1"]):not(:focus)::before {
  color: #e81534;
  background-color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
```

```html
<div class="editable" data-placeholder="Ingrese texto...">
  <br data-mce-bogus="1">
</div>
```

Y cuando escribo dentro, TinyMCE lo cambia a: **(Aquí está correcto, ya que no debe mostrar el placeholder)**

```css
div.editable:first-child:has([data-mce-bogus="1"]):not(:focus)::before {
  color: #e81534;
  background-color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
```

```html
<div class="editable" data-placeholder="Ingrese texto...">
  Aquí el texto nuevo que ingrese.
</div>
```

Pero si doy un salto de línea, TinyMCE lo cambia a: **(Incorrecto ya no debería de aparecer el placeholder)**

```css
div.editable:first-child:has([data-mce-bogus="1"]):not(:focus)::before {
  color: #e81534;
  background-color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
```

```html
<div class="editable" data-placeholder="Ingrese texto...">
  <p>Aquí el texto nuevo que ingrese.</p>
  <p>
    <br data-mce-bogus="1">
  </p>
</div>
```

Ahora lo que estoy buscando de acuerdo a como me modifica los escenarios TinyMCE quisiera saber si el primer hijo directo de `div.editable` es `<br data-mce-bogus="1">` ya que solo necesito agregar el `content: attr(data-placeholder);` cuando este sea el primer hijo directo, que no lo busque dentro de todo el div así como pasa cuando también es hijo de un `<p>` *(el ultimo escenario)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El selector que estas buscando es este:

```
div.editable:has(>*[data-mce-bogus="1"]:first-child)::before
```

Explicando el selector por partes

`div.editable` << elemento div con clase editable

`div.editable:has(...)` << funcion "has" para saber si tiene el selector(uno o más elementos según el selector) dentro de la funcion

`>*` >> la flecha indica hijos inmediato, es decir, el siguiente nivel pero no mas niveles de profundidad, el asterisco indica cualquier elemento y juntos significan "cualquier hijo del primer nivel de profundidad"

`[data-mce-bogus="1"]:first-child` >> este selector implica que tenga el atributo data-mce-bogus="1" y ademas que sea primer hijo

NOTA: este selector devuelve el `"div.editable"` ya que el pseudo elemento `::before` no puede ser usado en un elemento `br`

```css
div.editable:has(>*[data-mce-bogus="1"]:first-child)::before {
  color: #e81534;
  background-color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="editable" data-placeholder="Ingrese texto...">
  <p>texto1</p>
  <p>texto2</p>
</div>

<div class="editable" data-placeholder="Ingrese texto...">
  <br data-mce-bogus="1">
  <p>texto2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciono a la perfección, necesito darle una repasada a fondo a psudoelementos y psudoselectores, muchas gracias.